# How to make Open Graph tags dynamic using Svelte

Tags: facebook-opengraph, svelte

I was making a website using Svelte and as I was adding more features, I wanted to customize link previews using Open Graph and Twitter tags. My website, similarily to YouTube, needs to change OG tags based on query strings. How can I do that?

I'll be glad for any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Same here, it's working for me locally, but when deployed it is undefined. I'm using this package svelte-meta-tags.